# Как получить ссылки со страницы?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

```
Есть такой код. Нужно со страницы получить ссылки с классом "btn-warning". $(".btn-warning") возвращает в хроме nodelist в firefox htmlcollection. Индексированный доступ возращает какую-то пустоту. .item(idx) тоже бред выдает.
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
      <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<a class="btn-warning" href="">a</a><br>
<a class="btn-warning" href="">b</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [В чем трабл?][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/ZF3eL/

Comment: трабл в том что не могу получить элементы <a> из DOM

Comment: Спасибо большое, Deonis. Ваш пример помог разобраться!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@prozac631](/users/10408/prozac631)](/users/10408/prozac631), вы их уже получили, т.к. написали, что

> возвращает в хроме nodelist в firefox htmlcollection

Вопрос теперь в том, что вы собираетесь с этим делать? Вам нужно значения атрибутов, текст этих ссылок или что еще? Как в [этом примере](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/ZF3eL/1/)